# Error after update to STS 3.6.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have updated STS to version 3.6.4.RELEASE. When I try to start my java project, I get this error message in the console:

> Fehler: Hauptklasse Files.springsource.vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE.base-instance.conf.logging.properties konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden

This means in english:

> Error: main class Files.springsource.vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE.base-instance.conf.logging.properties could not be found or loaded

Does someone have a solution for this problem? I have cleaned my project and the server, but the error still occurs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In "Project Explorer" view right click on "Servers"
- Select "Run As"
- Select "Run Configurations..." (That should bring up the "Run Configurations"
  window)
- Select the tc server you are using (The problem is the same with tc Server V2.9 and tc Server V3.0-V3.01)
- Select tab "Arguments"
- In VM Arguments replace

  - -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/Program Files/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE/base-instance/conf/logging.properties
  - -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\Program Files\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.3.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\logging.properties"

Comment: This issue has wasted massive amounts of my time over the last few months. Many thanks for posting this fix. This needs to be reported as a bug.

Comment: You might want to emphasize what is being replaced.  good answer though

Comment: i cannot wait for the day where we programmers will look back and laugh at such trivial problems ... he says 15 years later.

Answer (score 0):

What are the templates set on your server instance?
Try creating a new tc server instance. Right-clicking in the servers view and follow the wizard to create a new instance with your 2.9.3 runtime. Run your app o a new instance
Check if you tc server 2.9.3 runtime environment is still valid (via Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment) that it still points to the right folder.